# Возможно ли в тернарном операторе произвести зависимое от переменной умножение символов

Tags: java

Возможно ли как то упростить код метода:

```
        public String say() {
            if(i<=0) return name +" спит.";
            else {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    sb.append("я");
                }
                return name + " говорит м"+sb+"у!";
            }
        }
```

До типа такого:

```
        public String say() {
            return i<=0?name+" спит.":name + " говорит м"+'я'*i+"у!";
        }
```

Я понимаю, что 'я'*i не правильно. Это образный пример.

Comment: можно написать функцию возвращающую  `'я'*i` и использовать ее в тернарном операторе. Определите код который после `else` как отдельную функцию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так, без лишних методов и повторов переменных.

```
 public String sayOrSleep(int i, String name) {
      return name + ((i<=0) ? " спит." : " говорит м"+
        String.format("%0" + i + "d", 0).replace("0","я")+"у!");
 }
```

Зачем писать костыль, когда уже все написано до Вас для подобных случаев :)

Comment: согласен, Ваше решение лучше.

Comment: Знатный костыль. Но, если ваш код будут читать другие, то **какой-нибудь** `StringUtils.repeat("я", i)` будет гораздо понятнее.

Comment: @Nofate Я предложил метод без библиотек. Вы может не в курсе, что в стандартном языке этого класса нет, и что StringUtils подключаемая библиотека из apache? А почему не через Guava Strings это написать? Strings.repeat("я", i); - это же еще короче и понятнее!

Comment: Я не давал отсылок на конкретную библиотеку. Это вполне может быть `StringUtils`, написанный самим ТС.

Comment: @Nofate Конечно, начать писать свой StringUtils c функцией repeat, и потом его расширять другими функциями, вот это не разу не костыль, лучше уж apache подключить сразу. Спора нет, что удобнее читать если эту функцию если вынести ее в отдельный класс, просто стояла задача по максимальному упрощению кода и она сделана без библиотек и создания доп. классов, в один метод.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String say() {
    return i <= 0 ? name + " спит." : name + " говорит м" + multiplyCharYa(i) + "у!";
}

public String multiplyCharYa(int i){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         sb.append("я");
     }
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

С использование Java 8 можно воспользоваться комбинацией [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) и методом [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
public String sayOrSleep() {
    return name + (i <= 0 ? " спит." : " говорит м" + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, "я")) + "у!");
}
```

Еще вариант с использованием [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
public String sayOrSleep() {
    return name + (i <= 0 ? " спит." : " говорит м" + Collections.nCopies(i, "я").stream().collect(Collectors.joining("")) + "у!");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно об этом я и спрашивал! Жаль что только с Java 8, но радует, что появилось!